# _mm_storeu_si128 cost too much time?

Tags: c, sse, intrinsics

This is a C fuction, which gets weight values of `src` and stores them into `dst`.

```
static int _medium_c( DCTELEM * src, int index, int *dst )
{
    int i;
    //get weighted value
    for( i = 0; i < 16; i++ )
    {
        unsigned int threshold1 = threshold[index][i];//threshold contains constant value
        unsigned int threshold2 = ( threshold1<<1 );
        int level= src[i];
        if( ( ( unsigned )( level+threshold1 ) ) > threshold2 )
        {
            if( ( ( unsigned )( level+2*threshold1 ) ) > 2*threshold2 )
            {
                dst[i] = level * factor[i];
            }
            else
            {
                if( level>0 )
                {
                    dst[i] =  2*( level - ( int )threshold1 ) * factor[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    dst[i] =  2*( level + ( int )threshold1 ) * factor[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The intrinsic version is:

```
int medium_intrinsic16( DCTELEM * src, int index, int* dst )
{
   int i, j = 0,  c[16], k = 0;
   for( j = 0;j < 2;j++ )
   {
        __m128i zero128 = _mm_setzero_si128();
        __m128i mask = _mm_set_epi8( 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80,0x0d, 0x0c,0x09,0x08,0x05,0x04,0x01,0x00 );
        __m128i factor_a  = _mm_loadu_si128 ( (__m128i*)&factor[8*j] );
        factor_a = _mm_shuffle_epi8( factor_a, mask);
        __m128i factor_b  = _mm_loadu_si128 ( (__m128i*)&factor[8*j+4] );
        factor_b = _mm_shuffle_epi8( factor_b, mask);
        factor_a = _mm_unpacklo_epi64( factor_a, factor_b );

        __m128i  level_a  = _mm_loadu_si128( (__m128i*)&src[8*j] );

        __m128i  threshold1_a = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&threshold[index][8*j] );
        threshold1_a = _mm_shuffle_epi8( threshold1_a, mask);
        __m128i  threshold1_b = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&threshold[index][8*j+4] );
        threshold1_b = _mm_shuffle_epi8( threshold1_b, mask);
        threshold1_a = _mm_unpacklo_epi64( threshold1_a, threshold1_b );
        __m128i  threshold2_a = _mm_slli_epi32( threshold1_a, 1 );

        __m128i mif = _mm_cmpgt_epi16( level_a, zero128 );
        //keep
        __m128i m0 = _mm_sub_epi16( level_a, threshold1_a );//( level - ( int )threshold1 )
        __m128i m1 = _mm_add_epi16( level_a, threshold1_a );//( level + ( int )threshold1 )
        __m128i m2 = _mm_slli_epi16( factor_a, 1);

        __m128i m3 = _mm_mullo_epi16( m0, m2 );//2*( level - ( int )threshold1 ) * factor[i];
        __m128i m4 = _mm_mulhi_epi16( m0, m2 );//2*( level - ( int )threshold1 ) * factor[i];
        __m128i m5 = _mm_mullo_epi16( m1, m2 );//2*( level + ( int )threshold1 ) * factor[i];
        __m128i m6 = _mm_mulhi_epi16( m1, m2 );//2*( level + ( int )threshold1 ) * factor[i];

        //keep
        m3 = _mm_blendv_epi8( m5, m3, mif);
        m4 = _mm_blendv_epi8( m6, m4, mif);

        m0 = _mm_add_epi16( level_a, threshold2_a );//( level+2*threshold1 )
        m1 = _mm_slli_epi16( threshold2_a, 1 );//2*threshold2
        m2 = _mm_max_epu16( m0, m1 );
        mif = _mm_cmpeq_epi16( m2, m0 );
        m0 = _mm_mullo_epi16( level_a, factor_a );
        m1 = _mm_mulhi_epi16( level_a, factor_a );

        //keep
        m0 = _mm_blendv_epi8( m3, m0, mif );
        m1 = _mm_blendv_epi8( m4, m1, mif );

        m2  = _mm_add_epi16( level_a, threshold1_a );
        m3  = _mm_max_epu16( m2, threshold2_a );
        mif = _mm_cmpeq_epi16( m3, m2);

        m0 = _mm_and_si128( mif, m0 );
        m1 = _mm_and_si128( mif, m1 );

        m2 = _mm_unpacklo_epi16( m0, m1 );
        m3 = _mm_unpackhi_epi16( m0, m1 );
        _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)&dst[8*j] , m2 );//will run fast if removed 
        _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)&dst[8*j+4], m3 );//will run fast if removed      
    }  
    return 0;
}
```

The intrinsic version is not faster then C version.The problem is if I remove the last 2 lines of the for loop, as indicted in the codes , `_mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)&dst[8*j] , m2)` and `_mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)&dst[8*j+4], m3)`, the intrinsic version will run faster signicantly than c version( about 4 times faster ).  Could anyone explain why this happens? Does `_mm_storeu_si128()` cost so much time? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're probably bottlenecked on memory bandwidth if it's the same speed as the C version.  In that case, yes, storing to memory is the most expensive thing in your algorithm.

Or perhaps the compiler optimizes away a lot of code when the results aren't stored anywhere!  You'd have to look at the asm to make sure it just left out the store instructions, instead of optimizing away most of your function.

See http://agner.org/optimize/, and other links at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info (esp. Ulrich Drepper's paper about caches.)

Look into cache blocking, aka loop tiling.

Comment: One more question. Is there method to identify if the problem is caused by cache blocking?

Comment: @AlexLEE: cache blocking is a technique to avoid memory-bandwidth bottlenecks, by working in small blocks that fit in the cache.  You can identify it with a profiler, esp. one that can read the CPU performance counters.  Look for a large amount of cache misses.